# SimpleCv - IOError("cannot identify image file") - from JpegStreamCamera() - IP Webcam for Android

Tags: python, opencv, simplecv

I'm trying to use my Android 2.3 phone with IP Webcam app to display using SimpleCV. The following seems fine.

```
from SimpleCV import *
import time

cam = JpegStreamCamera("http://192.168.1.3:1025/videofeed") 
img = cam.getImage() 
img.show()
```

But, on running I get the following error. The app on phone detects the connection though.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\cam.py", line 5, in <module>
    img = cam.getImage()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\SimpleCV\Camera.py", line 540, in getImage
    return Image(pil.open(StringIO(self.camthread.currentframe)), self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pil-1.1.7-py2.7-win32.egg\Image.py", line 1980, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

Is there any way to detect the format of webcam stream and convert this stream to jpeg? Any other suggestions? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: getting the same error with static png images for template matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and is now actually fixed up in the master branch at:
https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV

Answer (score 0):

It should actually already be in a Jpeg format.  Can you start the IP webcam software again and then verify that URL works in chrome or firefox.  If it doesn't than there is something wrong with the URL.

Comment: Checked it several times. URL works fine in FF and Chrome. The cam feed works fine when used with C# opencvsharp. However in C# case I did not use the IP address. 
http://www.prodigyproductionsllc.com/articles/programming/opencv-eye-tracking-with-c/

CvCapture cap = CvCapture.FromCamera(1)
does the task. 

In python-simplecv, is this error because my phone's cam is high res?? Any other solution to get this one working?

Comment: What version of simplecv are you using?

Comment: The latest one. 1.2 on Win7 64bit. Tried on 32bit also. I don't think it matters.
http://space.dl.sourceforge.net/project/simplecv/1.2/simplecv-setup-1.2.exe

Comment: I think there was a bug with the JpegStreamer in 1.2, can you update to the latest development version.

Comment: I'll try and get back with the result.